# Get the column number by propertyName from Grid using Vaadin 7.4.9

Tags: grid, vaadin

I want get the column number from my grid. How I can get it ?

```
Grid grid = new Grid();
IndexedContainer container = new IndexedContainer();
grid.setContainerDataSource(container);
container.addContainerProperty("name", String.class, "");
container.addContainerProperty("surname", String.class, "");
container.addContainerProperty("age", Integer.class, 0);
```

I get the solution:

```
List list = grid.getColumns();


for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    System.out.println(list.get(i) + " is on position: " + i);
```

Comment: Can you share what have you tried? The function you use to calculate the position or something similar.

Comment: @Shirkam I dont have any ideas, that is a reason why I wrote my post

Comment: So, I'm reading below that you want a function that by ej: "name" returns 3. Is that an arbitrary number? Or just a random result that may be. On the other hand. Why would you need that function? But, have you tried to iterate over grid columns?

Comment: You can use https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Grid.html#getColumns-- and get its property ids.

Comment: @Shirkam I need that for sort, when i export data to excel ... Long story :D

Comment: Have you tried anything that I told you? I'm not at my pc, so I can't write a propper answer, but, that should work.

Comment: @Shirkam when I try use getPropertyId, that return me only the same name -> e.g when I use this code, it return Milka too ... :( Notification.show(grid.getColumn("Milka").getPropertyId()+"");

Comment: @Shirkam but I get the solution now, with the code: List list = grid.getColumns();
         
         
         for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
          System.out.println(list.get(i));

Comment: Oh, I misswrite that! I was meaning that you can obtain column id's with that method, but you came with the solution despite that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution is:**

```
List list = grid.getColumns();

for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
System.out.println(list.get(i) + " is on position: " + i);
```